# Почему header плавает?

Tags: css

На некоторых страницах header лежит нормально, а на некоторых слишком высоко, везде подключаю один и тот же header.На некоторых страницах приходиться менять значение margin-top: -20px. Можете сами зайти на сайт убедиться в этом, попадете на главную страницу,а потом зайдите по кнопке регистрация, хедер уже не так ровно лежит.  [сайт](http://v-sporte.net)

```
.header{
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:-40px;
    background:#36638e;
    border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    height: 50px; /* футера */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. смотрим на скриншот
2. убираем из хедера margin-top: -40px;
3. убираем лишние артефакты, которые отмечены красным (они где то у вас в коде неведомым образом прописаны)
4. никогда не используйте кучу синего и красного цветов одновременно. а то глаза вылазят от боли

[image]

Уберите артефакты http://prntscr.com/3o08bx

Comment: Лишние артефакты не удалось найти и удалить. Не получилось сделать так как вы сказали, сейчас сверху просто пустое место. А цвета просто так поставлены, чтоб лучше ориентироваться.

Comment: В дополнение, закройте тег </head>

Comment: dekameron, закрыт же, даже на скрине и в коде.

Comment: @lifting, у вас лишний тег http://prntscr.com/3nznj7
и вообще, каким редактором кода вы пользуетесь?

Comment: mountpoint, Notepad, все равно нет.

Comment: @lifting, обновил ответ. Вы вообще форматируете код?